# React Native iOS Blank White Screen and EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: ios, react-native, crash

I am using React Native 0.55.4. When I am testing the iOS build in debug on simulator or release on a device, it is working fine for a few minutes then suddenly, it will give blank white screen and stuck. I have to kill the app and restart it on the device or Cmd + R in the simulator to get it working.

Following is the screenshots I took.

[image]

It is the screenshot when I get the white screen. It doesn't complain anything in RN debugger tool too. I don't think it is a crash but I can be wrong.

After a few minutes, I get the following.

[image]

Has anyone faced this problem before? Any suggestions or tips are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you show your The Script Build Phases in Xcode?

Comment: I don't see "run script" in build phases in xcode but I have some scripts for sentry as following:

    export SENTRY_PROPERTIES=sentry.properties
    ../node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli upload-dsym


and 

    export SENTRY_PROPERTIES=sentry.properties
    export NODE_BINARY=node
    ../node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli react-native xcode 
    ../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh

Comment: and Pod Manifest locks

diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    # print error to STDERR
    echo "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." >&2
    exit 1
fi
# This output is used by Xcode 'outputs' to avoid re-running this script phase.
echo "SUCCESS" > "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"


Are they what you need..? If not, please let me know how to get what you need :D Thanks.

Comment: I think this is export NODE_BINARY=node  issue.node didn't get proper path.

Comment: change script some thing like this export NODE_BINARY=yourpath(/Users/myname/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/node)
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh

Comment: I managed to make it work .. actually, i was using react navigation and I put true for swipeEnabled. one developer suggested to put false and now it is not showing white screen anymore. For the network crash, I patched the codes from this pull request: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/19489/files :) 

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Happy to Help :)